# Flagging abusive comments

Tags: support

It's occurred to me that there is a specific user here that has a bad habit of making directly aggressively rude comments implying or directly stating that people are stupid or ignorant when they disagree with him.  I started flagging these but the message is something like '10 more to go'.  Does it make sense to require that many users to flag a comment in order to trigger action?  It doesn't seem like the community is active enough in flagging things for that to be an effective standard.  Also, is there anyone looking at the overall level of flags for a user?

I'm not perfect and everyone has bad days but this is behavior that has been repeated over years and continues to this day.  I'm guessing that a lot of people are hardened to such things especially when they come from a bit of a crank but is that really something we should be tolerating?

Comment: There’s a fine line with behavior, but direct insults cross that line and we’ll always react to a flag there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do flag comments as rude and abusive if they meet the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/132930). We do monitor this and have a range of options available to us if there is a pattern of bad behaviour.

I think the "10 more to go" message is about how many flags from normal users it would require before the content was automatically removed without moderator intervention. Either that or it's the number of flags you have left for the day, if you've been using them heavily. Anyway, flags are also raised to moderators and in practice in most cases we would look at them and resolve them before the threshold of user flags was reached.

Comment: I wasn't sure that flagging was seen by moderators if it didn't meet the threshold but I didn't ask that clearly.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The "10 more to go" (actually "10 remaining") is actually how many number of flags the OP has left for the day. The system never shows how many flags still needed to remove the comment ([although, the answer is `3 + comment score/3`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365))